# PHP, error_reporting(), 6143 triggers also E_DEPRECATED (8192)

Tags: php, error-handling

When I use below (simplified) error handling with `$notice` then it does catch `E_DEPRECATED` (8192) errors.

With `$notice`, the value is 6143, the bitmask for that is:

0001011111111111

And that does not include the bit for `E_DEPRECATED`, which is below.

0010000000000000

I don't understand why this error handling does also catch `E_DEPRECATED` (8192) errors.

```
$error   = (int)            E_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR;
$warning = (int) $error   | E_WARNING | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_USER_WARNING;
$notice  = (int) $warning | E_NOTICE | E_USER_NOTICE;
$all     = (int) $notice  | E_STRICT | E_DEPRECATED | E_USER_DEPRECATED;

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    echo "$errno - $errfile:$errline $errstr") ;
}

error_reporting($notice);
set_error_handler("error_handler");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your error handler will be called by every error. In order take the error_reporting level into account you will need to do this manually:

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        return;
    }
    echo "$errno - $errfile:$errline $errstr") ;
}
```

Also you can limit error level when binding it. In your case:

```
set_error_handler("error_handler", $notice);
```

See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING)?>
```